# What is a Semantical Error Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am getting this error

```
[Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException]                            
[Semantical Error] Couldn't find constant CJBusinessBundle:PO:new, method 
CJ\BusinessBundle\Controller\ProductController::createAction().
```

My Annotation Part

```
/**
 * Creates a new Product entity.
 *
 * @Route("/", name="product_create")
 * @Method("POST")
 * @Template(CJBusinessBundle:PO:new.html.twig)
 */
```

I don't understand what would be the issue with this

Comment: You forgot the quotes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wrap your template definition in quotes.
Otherwise it's looking for it in a PHP constant when the annotation gets looked up, and that is the error you are seeing as there is no constant with that name.

```
/**
 * Creates a new Product entity.
 *
 * @Route("/", name="product_create")
 * @Method("POST")
 * @Template("CJBusinessBundle:PO:new.html.twig")
 */
```

Comment: You need to add `.html.twig` or a 'Unable to find template' error would happen